# How can I check if the user's input values are negative and eventually ask the user to insert them again?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, operators

I am trying to prompt a user to enter two non negative values. If the user inputs a negative value the program asks user to re-enter a non negative value. Here is what my C program looks like thus far, please explain if I am misusing operators.

```
int main()
{    
    int a,b;
    do {
        printf("enter two positive integers\n");
        scanf("%d""%d", &a, &b);
    } while (a<0 || b<0);

    printf("thank you");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you included `#include <stdio.h>` at the beginning of your program ? You need this to get access to printf and scanf.

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting an error message (and if so, what is it)? Is the code not doing what you intend (and if so, what is it doing and what did you expect instead)?

Comment: no error message joe. my problem is that i want to ask the user to input two values if the first is <0 reprompt, abd than move on to the next input value until both inputs are positive. my question is....is there any way to set this code up using a do while loop? or while loop

Comment: yes francis i included that segment of code i just forgot to include it in my post

Answer (score 2):

Even though some people think

```
 scanf("%d""%d", &a, &b);
```

is wrong, and should be changed to:

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
```

It **is not**. It is **regular** in C. **Adjacent string literals** are concatenated automatically.

Nevertheless there is no need to use that much `"` symbols for no particular use.

Comment: -1, that's just wrong. Adjacent string literals are concatenated automatically, that's basic C.

Comment: It is not wrong, it is better practice to write it like this.

Comment: It is wrong, since it's not an answer: the change you point out will not help the poster to get the code to work. Thus, down-voted.

Comment: unwind are you saying that each variable must have its own string to check each of the values and report back if a user must re enter a integer or move on to the next part of the program for each? I am trying to cut my code down is this not possible for this part of the program?

Answer (score 2):

You must check the return value of `scanf()`. Unless it returns `2`, you cannot rely on `a` and `b` both having valid values.

Checking the return value of `scanf()` can be done directly, for instance you could have:

```
if(scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) == 2)
{
  if(a >=0 && b >= 0)
    break;
}
```

But, that said, it's often better to do this in *two steps*:

1. Read a full line of input from the user, using `fgets()`.
2. Try to scan out the two numbers from that single line, using `sscanf()`. Note the additional `s` at the start of the function name, here!

The above makes it more robust, since `scanf()` has rather complicated handling of whitespace.

Comment: thats where my issue lies rob i am trying to check the return value on one variable and if it is negative prompt the user to re enter a positive value and than enter the second integer and repeat the process until both a and b are positive. i am still a little iffy on the use of scanf function. how would i be able to check the return values?

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine except you have an extra \" in your scanf. It should be:

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
```

Comment: thanks wizkid that will certainly help cut down my code